# React - Unable to render images on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, heroku

I deployed a full stack web application on heroku.

The react images rendered using *css files* are showing fine on the deployed webpage. But the ones which are loading using ***import img from './img.jpg'*** are not showing on the webpage.

**NOTE**: They are showing fine on local machine (dev).

What could be the reason and what would be the solution to this?

> React Component:

```js
// images
import American from './American1.jpg';
import Italian from './Italian1.jpg';
import Indian from './Indian1.jpg';
import Chinese from './Chinese1.jpg';


// array for images
const foods = [American, Indian, Italian, Chinese];

// how they're being rendered
<div className="row justify-content-between">
    {foods.map((food, i) => {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 my-3" key={foodsNames[i]}>
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-11">
                        <Card className="MainCard">
                            <div className="card-image">
                                
                             // images used below
                                <Card.Img className="image" variant="top" src={food} />
                             // image used above 

                            </div>

                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title className="card-title">{foodsNames[i]}</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928682/html-pictures-not-showing-up-on-heroku

Comment: Probably not because this tells to save the pictures in the public folder but the react app doesn't let you import the images from outside the src directory.

Comment: it actually does. In fact you will find that all the icons and logos that come bundled with ```create-react-app``` to be in the public folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your images to public folder, and access it like below in your component.
I have my image (brand_icon.png) in direcory public/images

```
<img alt='' src={'../images/brand_icon.png'} />
```